# Calling custom class from di xml?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, dependency-injection

I have 2 classes A and B.

A is overridden from Magentos core class say M1 and it is defined in di.xml as:

```
<preference for="Magento\..\M1" type="Namespace\Module\..\A" />
```

Now Class B is my custom class and it is not overriding any core class.

1. Do i have to define B in di.xml?
2. If so, how?

My B class __construct() is as:

```
public function __construct(
\Custom\Helper $myHelper,
array $data = []
)
{
  $this->helper=$myHelper;
 }
```

I dont have any Bactory or Proxy in my signature.

Answer (score 1):

If the constructor signatures where you use `B`, look like one of these

```
__construct(B $b)
__construct(B\Proxy $b)
__construct(BFactory $bfactory)
```

then you don't need to define preferences and the object manager will automatically instantiate a `B` class for you (or generate a proxy/factory).

You only need preferences if the type hint in the constructor is not *exactly the same* type that you want to instantiate.

For example, if you have

```
__construct(BInterface $b)
```

with `B implements BInterface`, you need a preference like this:

```
<preference for="BInterface" type="B" />
```

Comment: I have updated my B class constructor()

Comment: I was referring to the constructors of the classes where you **use** B